# PostGIS slow intersects query

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I'm having trouble optimizing this query, sometimes it will take around 10s to execute. I have indexed the columns samples.geom and jbb2016.geom_3021 so that shouldn't be a problem.
I know this is surely a common question, but I have not found a solution to this slow query in my searchings.

Here's some info about my PostGIS installation: *POSTGIS="2.3.0 r15146"*

PostgreSQL version: *PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0*

The samples table contains about 400k rows the geometry is points, the jbb2016 contains about 1.25m rows the geometry there is some kind of multipolygon.

```
SELECT 
year, customer_id, COUNT(customer_id) AS samples, 
(SELECT name || ' ' || last_name FROM customers WHERE id = customer_id) as name
FROM samples
WHERE 
ST_Intersects(
    (SELECT geom_3021 FROM jbb2016 WHERE blockid = 62023246713), samples.geom
)
GROUP BY year, customer_id 
ORDER BY year DESC;
```

Comment: It is a common question, though never a common problem (because every query is different). Every question here has always resulted in a comment requesting the query plan (generated by [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-explain.html)). Just on the face of it, your query is hyperinefficient due to subquery use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ST_Intersects might not use the indexes because of the subquery inside.
Better to use JOIN

```
SELECT 
year, customer_id, COUNT(customer_id) AS samples, 
(SELECT name || ' ' || last_name FROM customers WHERE id = customer_id) as name
FROM samples
JOIN (SELECT geom_3021 FROM jbb2016 WHERE blockid = 62023246713) jbb2016
ON ST_Intersects(jbb2016.geom_3021, samples.geom)
GROUP BY year, customer_id 
ORDER BY year DESC;
```

Comment: The query you provided ran in 1.2s compared to 8.3s. Thank you, I will keep the possibility to a JOIN in mind.